# Unit Testing : what to test / what not to test?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Since a few days ago I've started to feel interested in Unit Testing and TDD in C# and VS2010. I've read blog posts, watched youtube tutorials, and plenty more stuff that explains why TDD and Unit Testing are so good for your code, and how to do it.

But the biggest problem I find is, that I don't know what to check in my tests and what not to check.

I understand that I should check all the logical operations, problems with references and dependencies, but for example, should I create an unit test for a string formatting that's supossed to be user-input? Or is it just wasting my time while I just can check it in the actual code?

Is there any guide to clarify this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In TDD every line of code must be justified by a failing test-case written **before** the code.

This means that you cannot develop **any** code without a test-case. If you have a line of code (condition, branch, assignment, expression, constant, etc.) that can be modified or deleted without causing any test to fail, it means this line of code is useless and *should be* deleted (or you have a missing test to support its existence).

That is a bit extreme, but this is how TDD works. That being said if you have a piece of code and you are wondering whether it should be tested or not, you are not doing TDD correctly. But if you have a string formatting routine or variable incrementation or whatever small piece of code out there, there *must* be a test case supporting it.

#### UPDATE (use-case suggested by *Ed.*):

> Like for example, adding an object to a list and creating a test to see if it is really inside or there is a duplicate when the list shouldn't allow them.

Here is a counterexample, you would be surprised how hard it is to spot copy-paste errors and how common they are:

```
private Set<String> inclusions = new HashSet<String>();
private Set<String> exclusions = new HashSet<String>();

public void include(String item) {
    inclusions.add(item);
}

public void exclude(String item) {
    inclusions.add(item);
}
```

On the other hand testing `include()` and `exclude()` methods alone is an overkill because they do not represent any use-cases by themselves. However, they are probably part of some business use-case, you should test instead.

Obviously you shouldn't test whether `x` in `x = 7` is really `7` after assignment. Also testing generated getters/setters is an overkill. But it is the easiest code that often breaks. All too often due to copy&paste errors or typos (especially in dynamic languages).

#### See also:

- [Mutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing)

Comment: +1, but this is really extreme and often not worth it for me, see my answer. Also, if you have a bunch of lines implementing a performance optimization, does it mean that you have *unit* tests measuring performance? Otherwise the lines would be considered redundant by your logic.

Comment: In my example I was thinking about a String that the final user should write inside a Text-Box. I suppose that this must be checked, as formatting is crucial, but sometimes I feel like I'm thinking about testing the language, not the logic.

Like for example, adding an object to a list and creating a test to see if it is really inside or there is a duplicate when the list should't allow them.

Comment: Your desire to test something should be directly proportional to the probability of that thing breaking and its importance to the end product. If it doesn’t matter, don’t test it. If it can’t break (like accessors synthesized by the compiler), don’t test it. If it’s a critical piece of the product, do whatever you can to test it.

Comment: This doesn't say much. You start with the super strict but clear definition: test every line including condition, branch, assignment, expression, constant, etc. Then you say, don't test everything, and give two examples. So what should and shouldn't be tested? Are you saying it's up to a programmer's own judgment?

Comment: You don't test lines, you test functions. You write enough tests that every line/branch in each function is executed at least once. The output of the functions must be correct and if it is you don't care about individual lines. You are then free to refactor your code with confidence as long as the tests all still pass. You can absolutely write tests for performance, too. You can't test private functions directly, only public functions which should fully exercise the private functions. If you have an unused private function it should be removed.

Answer (score 16):

Your first few TDD projects are going to probably result in **worse design**/redesign and **take longer** to complete as you are learning (at least in my experience).  This is why you shouldn't jump into using TDD on a large critical project.

My advice is to use **"pure" TDD** (acceptance/unit test everything test-first) on a **few small projects** (100-10,000 LOC).  Either do the side projects on your own or if you don't code in your free time, use TDD on small internal utility programs for your job.

After you do "pure" TDD on about 6-12 projects, you will start to understand how TDD affects design and **learn how to design for testability**.  Once you know how to design for testability, you will need to TDD less and **maximize the ROI** of unit, regression, acceptance, etc. tests rather than test everything up front.

For me, TDD is more of teaching method for good code design than a practical methodology.  However, I still TDD logic code and unit test instead of debug.

Comment: Yesterday as I was creating some small prototypes I became aware of this. It is really another completely new way to think in your code, so until my brain gets used to it it could take ages. And for a big project would be even worse.

Thanks a lot for your advices!

Answer (score 5):

There is no simple answer to this question. There is the law of diminishing returns in action, so achieving perfect coverage is seldom worth it. Knowing what to test is a thing of experience, not rules. It’s best to consciously evaluate the process as you go. Did something break? Was it feasible to test? If not, is it possible to rewrite the code to make it more testable? Is it worth it to always test for such cases in the future?

If you split your code into models, views and controllers, you’ll find that most of the critical code is in the models, and those should be fairly testable. (That’s one of the main points of MVC.) If a piece of code is critical, I test it, even if it means that I would have to rewrite it to make it more testable. If a piece of code is easy to get wrong or get broken by future updates, it gets a test. I seldom test controllers and views, as it’s not proving worth the trouble for me.

Comment: I was planning to use the MVC pattern in the next project so, even though what you said could be obvious once you think about it, that was very helpful.

Comment: I agree that "knowing what to test is a thing of experience, not rules."  But as a TDD newbie, the OP would be well-served by trying to err on the more-testing side of the spectrum so as to acquire that experience.

Answer (score 5):

The way I see it all of your code falls into one of three buckets:

1. Code that is easy to test: This includes your own deterministic public methods.
2. Code that is difficult to test: This includes GUI, non-deterministic methods, private methods, and methods with complex setup.
3. Code that you don't want to test: This includes 3rd party code, and code that is difficult to test and not worth the effort.

Of the three, you should focus on testing the **easy code**. The **difficult** to test code should be refactored so that into two parts: code that you don't want to test and easy code. And of course, you should test the refactored easy code.

Comment: Hi I would like to ask for methods that are in a framework where dependency will be injected during runtime, how should I test them in the first place if I don't even know know what the input are? For example the method is expecting HttpRequestMessage as input, how do I be sure that it would carry the thing I want?  How to mock it precisely?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should only unit test entry points to behavior of the system. This include public methods, public accessors and public fields, but not constants (constant fields, enums, methods, etc.). It also includes any code which directly deals with IO, I explain why further below.

My reasoning is as follows:

1. Everything that's public is basically an entry point to a behavior of the system. A unit test should therefore be written that guarantees that the expected behavior of that entry point works as required. You shouldn't test all possible ways of calling the entry point, only the ones that you explicitly require. Your unit tests are therefore also the specs of what behavior your system supports and your documentation of how to use it.
2. Things that are not public can basically be deleted/re-factored at will with no impact to the behavior of the system. If you were to test those, you'd create a hard dependency from your unit test to that code, which would prevent you from doing refactoring on it. That's why you should not test anything else but public methods, fields and accessors.
3. Constants by design are not behavior, but axioms. A unit test that verifies a constant is itself a constant, so it would only be duplicated code and useless effort to write a test for constants.

So to answer your specific example:

> should I create an unit test for a string formatting that's supossed
>   to be user-input?

Yes, absolutely. All methods which receive or send external input/output (which can be summed up as receiving IO), should be unit tested. This is probably the only case where I'd say non-public things that receive IO should also be unit tested. That's because I consider IO to be a public entry. Anything that's an entry point to an external actor I consider public.

So unit test public methods, public fields, public accessors, even when those are static constructs and also unit test anything which receives or sends data from an external actor, be it a user, a database, a protocol, etc.

*NOTE: You can write temporary unit tests on non public things as a way for you to help make sure your implementation works. This is more of a way to help you figure out how to implement it properly, and to make sure your implementation works as you intend. After you've tested that it works though, you should delete the unit test or disable it from your test suite.*

Answer (score 3):

Kent Beck, in Extreme Programming Explained, said you only need to test the things that need to work in production.

That's a brusque way of encapsulating both test-driven development, where every change in production code is supported by a test that fails when the change is not present; and You Ain't Gonna Need It, which says there's no value in creating general-purpose classes for applications that only deal with a couple of specific cases.

Comment: -- Kent Beck, Extreme Programming Explained, p. 58.
according to http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/development/policy/test-standard.xhtml?format=raw

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change your point of view.
In a pure form TDD requires the red-green-refactor workflow:

- write test (it must fail) RED
- write code to satisfy test GREEN
- refactor your code

So the question "What I have to test?" has a response like: "You have to write a test that correspond to a feature or a particular requirements".

In this way you get must code coverage and also a better code design (remember that TDD stands also for Test Driven "Design").

Generally speaking you have to test ALL public method/interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> should I create an unit test for a string formatting that's supossed
>   to be user-input? Or is it just wasting my time while I just can check
>   it in the actual code?

Not sure I understand what you mean, but the tests you write in TDD are supposed to test your production code. They aren't tests that check user input.

To put it another way, there can be TDD unit tests that test the user input validation *code*, but there can't be TDD unit tests that validate the user input itself.